# Why is the JFrame output different from its .paint method, and how to resolve this?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to set up a system that renders a quick list of items using Swing, as its layout managers suit my situation perfectly. However upon trying to use text wrapping I've found that the results shown in a demo JFrame differ from the results I'm getting from calling .print/.paint(All).

This is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TextWrapTest {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
        final GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        panel.add( new JLabel( "<html>This is a piece of text." ), gbc );
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add( new JLabel( "<html>This is a very long piece of text that needs to be wrapped in order to fit in the frame." ), gbc );
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add( new JLabel( "<html>Another piece of text." ), gbc );

        // Output the frame
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setUndecorated( true );
        frame.setSize( 200, 200 );
        frame.add( panel );

        frame.setVisible( true );

        // Output the image
        final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage( frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
        frame.paintAll( image.getGraphics() );
        ImageIO.write( image, "png", new File( "output.png" ) );
    }

}
```

The JFrame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbTPz.png
output.png: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcM4x.png

As you can see, the results are clearly different and the text refuses to wrap when drawn using .getGraphics()

I've been playing around with the GridBagConstraints and even tried text wrapping using JTextArea instead to no avail.

Any assistance in this matter would be appreciated, as I don't know how to get the paint method to obey text wrapping.

Yours sincerely,
Rens Rikkerink

Comment: First of all, you should avoid calling `paintAll` and stick to `printAll`, as this removes all the double buffering and some other related issues

Comment: You could also be in a race condition with the UI become realised and painted

Comment: @MadProgrammer this seems to be the issue. adding `Thread.sleep(1000);` resolved his issue

Comment: I ran you code, and it seemed to work fine (using `printAll`), however, I would "suggest" trying to wrap the image capture process into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` in attempt to allow the view to become realised on the screen, it "might" make a difference

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've tried both hoping to resolve this.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've just tried wrapping it in #invokeLater as you suggested, that indeed seemed to resolve the issue. If you would be so kind as to post it as an answer I'll accept it once I'm able.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons for this, but, I would recommend avoiding `paint` and `paintAll` as they invoke the double buffering aspects of the API and may cause delays before the image is actually painted to the `Graphics` context.  Instead, I'd recommend using `printAll` as it disables the double buffering while it's painting.

Another issue may be the fact that the frame may not be realised on the screen yet (or not even fully painted).  Calling `setVisible` invokes a lot of background work and will invoke call backs onto the EDT to get the painting process started.  In this case, I'd suggest using a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` block after the UI is made visible.

This will do a few things, firstly, I may put the task on the event queue AFTER the all the events that the frame create, but, more importantly, it will synchronise the painting, so you're not fighting the EDT trying to paint to the screen at the same time

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        frame.paintAll(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("output.png"));
    }
});
```